# Powershell print Excel list to PDF and configure print options

Tags: excel, powershell, pdf

So I am trying to automatically print an excel file to PDF.
So far so good, the file is being exported to PDF:

```
$filepath = "\\fileppath\file.xlsm"
$fileitem = Get-Item $filepath
$printdate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMdd")

try {
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excel.Visible = $false
    $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

    $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($fileitem.FullName)

    #Set PDF-printer
    #$excel.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
    $excel.ActivePrinter = "PDFPrint"
    #$wb.PaperSize = "A3"

    # Generate path of save destination PDF file
    $pdfpath = $fileitem.DirectoryName + "\" + $fileitem.BaseName + "_" + $printdate + 
".pdf"

    # Save as PDF
   
  $wb.ExportAsFixedFormat([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType]::xlTypePDF, $pdfpath)

$wb.Close($false)

$excel.Quit()
}
finally {
     # Release objects
     $sheet, $wb, $excel | ForEach-Object {
         if ($_ -ne $null) {
             [void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($_)
         }
    }
    stop-process -Id $PID
}
```

And here the problems begin:
I can't figure out how to set the right printer with papersize A3 and i would like to see today's date and time in the upper corner.

I believe because I use the printasfixedformat method i don't really use a printer like "Microsoft Print as PDF" but that's the only option I found online.

I found the library ImportExcel but it didn't really help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.papersize

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?